# Live software that recovers data when Operating System crashes?

Tags: backup, operating-systems

Can you tell me how to recover data from hard disk and backup it in another storage in case the operating system will not load or crashes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had some luck in the past using [System Rescue CD](http://www.sysresccd.org/Main_Page) - It is basically a live Linux disk with PhotoRec recovery software.

That being said, I sometimes have problems and by far, my favourite way of file recovery (if a disk is still readable) is to just get out the CD, put it in a working Windows computer and use either [Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva) for the light / accidental deletion job, or [R-Studio](http://www.data-recovery-software.net/) for anything half serious as I have not seen anything better.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean recover data from a disk which has *already* crashed, you might find recovery of the data impossible, or prohibitively expensive.

I think the best approach (the normal approach) is to regularly backup data to an external/remote drive, so that *if a disk does crash*, you go to your latest backup, and don't worry about 'recovering' data from the crashed disk.

Obviously, backups have to be done frequently. The more frequently, the better.

Comment: re: prohibitively expensive: i think the question is more about OS software crashes, not hardware HDD crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your OS. for windows acronis trueimage (there's no free version), macrium reflect (there's a free version) or any number of free imaging tools will work.

With linux bubackup might be worth looking at, or file level backups to tarballs